# Configuration error: Could not locate module when running unit test with vue-test-utils and jes

Tags: jestjs, vuejs3, ts-jest, vue-test-utils, babel-jest

Been struggling with this configuration error when unit testing with jest and vue-test-util. In detail, I'm testing total of 4 Vue components. The other 3 would pass just fine, but when running test for the fourth one, I ran into configuration issue for a file that is not used by the testing Vue Component:

Terminal Error:

```
 FAIL  tests/unit/panels/EditorContextPanel.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Configuration error:

    Could not locate module @/lib-components/assets/svg/Icons mapped as:
    C:\Users\nnguyen\Documents\NPM.AdvancedEditor.Components\src\$1.

    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/^@\/(.*)$/": "C:\Users\nnguyen\Documents\NPM.AdvancedEditor.Components\src\$1"
      },
      "resolver": undefined
    }

      1 | import { API, BlockAPI, BlockTool, BlockToolData } from '@ado/editorjs'
    > 2 | import Icons from '@/lib-components/assets/svg/Icons'
        | ^
      3 | import './styles/TableBlock.css'
      4 | import { defaultSanitizerConfig } from './configs/sanitizerConfig'
      5 |

      at createNoMappedModuleFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:579:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/lib-components/editor/BlockTools/TableBlock.ts:2:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 4 passed, 5 total
Tests:       10 passed, 10 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.308 s
Ran all test suites.
```

The testing file that ran into this issue:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import EditorContextPanel from '@/lib-components/panels/EditorContextPanel.vue'
import { createTestingPinia } from '@pinia/testing'
import { useApplicationStateStore } from '@/lib-components/stores/applicationStateStore'

describe('ContentToolsPanel', () => {
  it('panel visible when set', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(EditorContextPanel, {
      global: {
        plugins: [createTestingPinia()],
      },
    })
    const store = useApplicationStateStore()
    store.showEditorContextButtons = false
    expect(wrapper.find('[data-testid=editor-context-button]').isVisible).toBe(false)
    store.showEditorContextButtons = true
    expect(wrapper.find('[data-testid=editor-context-button]').isVisible).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

The Icon file that shows in the Terminal Error:

```
const Icons = {
  toolbarIcons: {
    bold: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path class="b" d="M13.6854,9.76a4.1607,4.1607,0,0,0,1.886-3.189A4.506,4.506,0,0,0,11.1314,2q-.066-.0009-.132,0H3.8564V18h8.046a4.334,4.334,0,0,0,1.783-8.24Zm-6.4-4.9h3.429a1.7145,1.7145,0,1,1,0,3.429H7.2854Zm4,10.286h-4v-3.432h4a1.7145,1.7145,0,1,1,0,3.429Z"/></svg>',
  }
};

export default Icons;
```

my jest config in package.json:

```
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "cache": false,
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts",
      "vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.vue$": "vue3-jest",
      "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": false,
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/tests/mocks/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/tests/mocks/styleMock.js",
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/lib-components/**/*.{vue,ts}",
      "!src/entry.esm.ts",
      "!src/entry.ts",
      "!**/main.ts",
      "!**/index.ts",
      "!**/styles/**",
      "!**/stubs/**",
      "!**/assets/**"
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "jest-serializer-vue"
    ],
    "preset": "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel",
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
```

I ran tests with `vue-cli-service test:unit --no-cache`. Any tips or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

check your import statements for your components are the correct casing as the actual file/folder name

```
import EditorContextPanel from '@/lib-components/panels/EditorContextPanel.vue'
import { createTestingPinia } from '@pinia/testing'
import { useApplicationStateStore } from '@/lib-components/stores/applicationStateStore'
```